# AJV JSONSchemaType Array Of Objects invalid

Tags: typescript, jsonschema, ajv

I am trying to define a simple schema for an array of objects, but typescript complains for the following:

```js
import { JSONSchemaType } from 'ajv';

const schema: JSONSchemaType<{ label: string; value: string }[]> = {
  type: 'array',
  items: {
    type: 'object',
    required: ['label', 'value'], // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
    properties: {
      label: { type: 'string' }, //  Property 'nullable' is missing in type '{ type: "string"; }' but required in type '{ nullable: true; const?: never; enum?: readonly string[]; default?: string; }'
      value: { type: 'string' }, //  Property 'nullable' is missing in type '{ type: "string"; }' but required in type '{ nullable: true; const?: never; enum?: readonly string[]; default?: string; }'
    },
  },
};
```

I am wondering what is wrong here. Changing the properties to `label: { type: 'string', nullable: true }` fixes the second error, but neither prop should be nullable.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Typescript: `4.0.3`

AJV: `7.2.3`

Comment: Having never used this package and just looking at the error messages, it seems like they want you to determine which properties are required by setting a property `nullable` on the property object rather than passing an array to the `required` property.  `required` seems like it should be `[]` or something else.

Comment: I just tried your code and I'm not seeing the error.  Maybe check that your packages are up to date?  Mine is ajv 7.2.3.  And make sure that `JSONSchemaType` is imported from `ajv` and not some other package.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. What TS version are you using? This error occurs for ajv v7.2.3 and ts v4.0.3.

Comment: I can confirm this is happening for me also when upgrading from ajv 6.12.6 to 7.2.3 . It seems like the schema definition changed since then, it does not allow required as an array of property names but each property should have it's own required configuration. As for nullable, seems like it is required as well.

Comment: for the required, try adding `const schema: JSONSchemaType<{ label: string; value: string }[], true>`

Answer (score 0):

Try with **version 8.12**.
I was getting **error** for having JSONSchemaType in AJV **version 6.**